# scrollTop() does this really do anything?

Tags: javascript

Has anyone gotten scrollTop() to scroll a div within a container? There are many questions about this.  But with this code the container div isn't scrolled to the selected element.

```
        $('div',$('#scroll_1')).each(function(){
        var this_text = $(this).text();
        if ( this_text.search(/now/i) != -1 || this_text.search(/soon/i) != -1 ) {
            this_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var scroll_top = $(this).offset().top;
            alert('id '+this_id+' '+scroll_top);
            $('#scroll_1').scrollTop(scroll_top);
            return false;
        }           
        });
```

The divs are added with a script as

```
$('#scroll_1').append('<div id="'+id+'">div html</div>');
```

The scroll_top comes as 0 whether .position().top or .offset().top is used. The script is called more than once. Each call has a different number for scroll_top but .scrollTop(scroll_top) doesn't scroll.

What is the right way to get the offset of the element div from the top of the container? There seem to be many questions about scrolling elements within a div.  Is there a way that works?  I'd prefer a method other than animation.

Answer (score 0):

[scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) does not accept any arguments, you probable meant doing:

```
....
$('#scroll_1').animate({
    scrollTop: scroll_top
}, 2000);
....
```

Comment: Is there a different way of doing a scrollTop to scroll the div?